# Listview of custom suggestions on map fragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

In my android I want to populate a Listview of custom suggestion for map loactions under fragment.I am not not getting any idea to do it.Thanks in avance
Actually I am having three items in that activity 1 editbox to search location,fragment and Listview.So when user enters any keyword in editbox  a webservice is called with that keyword which returns all the near by venues,so I want to show those venues in listview below fragments..

Comment: post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

As i understand that there are many markers in map, when user clicks on any of the marker, you have to populate the data in listview which is under mapView.

Use [OnInfoWindowClickListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener)

```
 @override
 public abstract void onInfoWindowClick (Marker marker) 
 {
    if(marker == referenceMarker)
    {
        UpdateListView(data);
    }
 }
```